# How to expand/zoom a cv2 window to the the full screen?

Tags: python, user-interface, opencv

When I run my program, I expect the window to look like this ([Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yn6K.png)), but I'm having a hard time to understand how to do that. Notice, that I marked with the red circle that this window is expanded or 'zoomed' (if I used Tkinter).

I figured out how to make it full screen using this piece of code ([Picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcQp9.jpg)):

```
cv2.namedWindow("Camera", cv2.WINDOW_GUI_EXPANDED)
cv2.setWindowProperty("Camera", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.imshow('Camera', frame1)
```

If I remove the second line of code, this is what I get ([Picture3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnTDw.png))

I tried to look up into the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d90/group__highgui__window__flags.html) , but still can't make it out.

If anybody has any ideas or insights how to do it, please share it with me.
Thanks to everyone in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.